# How to run a custom action after install which can run in quiet or a UI after Install (WIX)

Tags: command-line, wix, custom-action

I basically want to able to run an command line tool that already exists on the desired machine against the directory the files were run to.

I.e The Installer does the following:

Specify a location for the files to go into (INSTALLOCATION variable)

Then after copying has finished run a tool which will zip the files and attach them to attach them to another application.

```
<CustomAction Id="InstallTo" Return="check" Directory="INSTALLLOCATION"  Execute="immediate" ExeCommand='"C:\MyTool\Here\Tool.exe" -ad [INSTALLLOCATION] Poop 1.0'/>
        <InstallExecuteSequence>
            <Custom Action="InstallTo" After="InstallFinalize">$InstallTo&gt;2</Custom>
        </InstallExecuteSequence>
```

At the moment I'm not sure anyuthing is being called, is there a way to basically have this two step install and report progress if the tool failed/doesn't exist etc.

Thanks,
Jamie

Comment: Nobody have any ideas, that can do this?

Basically want to call an app which isn't included with the installer with the commands -ad INSTALLLOCATION Poop 1.0 where INSTALLLOCATION is a configurable directory either in the UI or via a parameter in the command line. I'd like to be able to get this in a CAQuietExec but if calls it and installs that would be great.

I'd appreciate any ideas people can give.

Cheers, Jamie

Answer (score 0):

Was a problem with our shell library requiring an extra slash.